# Don't show message on View display page

Tags: views, rules

I have some rules created and working fine. Some of them are made for messages, that are displaying after certain period of time. And that's alright, works. 
But, it also displays the message when browsing the page created in Views, that is listing all the content of X type.

So, let's say I have a *work* content type; Every *work* node older than few weeks is getting the message shown to the user. I also have a view, but I don't want the rules to display the message in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, answering myself. Turns out pure Rules are rather not enough.
But together with Path Rules (https://drupal.org/project/pathrules) it works without a problem. So, question answered, issue solved. Maybe it will help someone.